# Increasing Variables

Tags: python-2.7

So I am writing a program that will need to increase some variables by the amount that the user types. I thought a code like this would work:

```
var = 0
increase = input("Increase by: ")
var + increase
print(var)
```

But it just says that var is 0. I even tried making the input type int, `int(input(""))`

Still didn't work. Why won't it increase the variable?

**Keep in mind, I am using Python 2.7**

**EDIT** *It was solved! I just made it* `var += increase`

Comment: Use `var += increase` (which is shorthand for `var = var + increase`). Not just `var + increase`. You have not changed the value of `var`.

Comment: also keep in mind, what happens if i put in a negative number;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand the difference between a statement and an assignment.
You're making the statement var + increase, but its result is never used. You're basically asking the computer to evaluate it, but there is no side-effect (like printing it to the screen, sending it over the network or putting it somewhere in memory)

You can use the result of your statement in many ways, for example, you can print it directly:

```
print var + increase
```

Or you can assign it to a variable

```
var = var + increase
```

Even better, to a NEW variable:

```
result = var + increase
```

Actually, in python, if you make just a statement, it is not entirely lost, it's kept in a magic variable called "ans" which is denoted by an underscore (_).

So you could do

```
var + increase
print(_)
```

Comment: The only problem with print var+increase is it will not be usable later, if this is the final step, sure. Just be careful.

Comment: That is true. I've never written a line of python in my life, so I don't know when it's nice to use it, surely in the repl it could be. But I didn't want to lie and say it's discarded when it's not.

Comment: I like that 'magic variable' tidbit. never knew python kept it in 'ans' thanks. ill give you the +1 (even though i had the answer first:( )

Answer (score 0):

you're missing the setting of var. When you add var + increase it needs to be

```
var=var+increase. 
return var or print(var)
```

basically, you're adding var to increase without doing anything with the resulting sum.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update var. All you are doing in line 3 is assigning var + increase to ans. Try doing this:

```
var = 0
increase = input("Increase by: ")
var = var + increase
print var
```